# Running a JS code at XSL by Passing Value

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have a piece of code which populates a table with XSL. I have to modify it to integrate localization. I do localization just with a function call at JS side. However I couldn't run that JS code within my XSL. Here is what I've tried:

```
<xsl:when test="@name != ''">
  <tr>
    <td>
     <script>
      localizationResources.get('
     </script>
     <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
     <script>
      ')        
     </script>                          
    </td>
    <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </td>
   </tr>
</xsl:when>
```

My aim is to have a table row as *name* and value *pair* at which *name* is translated via my javascript call ( *localizationResources.get(KEY_FOR_TRANSLATION)* )

**EDIT:** This works:

```
<td>
    <script> alert(decodeURI('<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>')) </script>
</td>
```

However this doesn't:

```
<td>
    <script> decodeURI('<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>') </script>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run JavaScript code as, so to say, part of the XSLT transformng process at XSLT runtime (if this is what you tried). However, you can, of course, include JavaScript into an HTML file generated by XSLT. The JavaScript within the HTML file will then be normally executed in the browser.

I'd suggest to start with some very simple test, if your JavaScript code is executed at the point you want to have it and if the parameters passed through it via XSLT are corrected. Something like:

```
<td>
     <script>
      alert('<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>');
     </script>                          
</td>
```

Only downside of writing JavaScript code directly this way, is the handling of the greater than and less than operators in JavaScript. You have to escape them in XSLT.

Comment: I don't want to run that JavaScript code within XSL. It will be run at the HTML file which includes that XSL. So, it is exactly same thing what you do. However it doesn't generate anything. (also no error) i.e. this doesn't work too: `decodeURI('<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>')`